# How to structure my Android/Sugar app?

Tags: android, listview, orm, adapter

Could you give me some advice and answers for my questions about my app?

In my application, I have two activities: first contain a ListView. Every item in listview is filling up with Database data. Second activity includes webView. I am going to use a Sugar ORM as a database. Part of the data will show on the first activity (name, image) and part in the second activity (link for YouTube).

For download and caching images from web I will use a Picasso framework.

1) What kind of adapter should I use for my listView?

2) I didn't find in Sugar's documentation examples of how I can separately query data from Database. Like, I need some part to show in first activity and another part of data in second activity, but in official documentation I have only found this example "Load Entity"

```
Book book = Book.findById(Book.class, 1);
```

Comment: You're going to probably need a custom adapter, for all but the most trivial things you end up going that way.  As for querrying the db-  using an ORM doesn't remove the db.  Its just a layer on top of it.  You can query the db the same way you normally would.  Another note-  you aren't using Sugar ORM as a database, it isn't a database.  Its an ORM on top of a database.  That's an important distinction.

Comment: @GabeSechan oh thank you, man. I don't know about it. So Sugar ORM it's just a layer that makes an easy way to create and fills with data my database, right? And I need to create a reference to my class in which I store data(and which extends SugarRecord ) and call query() method? What constructor of query() method should i use if i am using Sugar ORM.

Comment: @GabeSechan and maybe i should use a Cursor ADapter to fill up with data my items?